# gamble two strategy

Tags: probability

You have $100\$$, and nevermind why, you have to convert it to $1000\$$.

Anything less is no
good. Your only way to make money is gamble for it. Your chance of winning one bet is $p$.

Here are two extreme strategies:

- Maximum strategy: bet as much as you can each time. To be smart, if you have less than
  $500\$$, you bet it all. If you have more , you bet enough to get to $1000\$$.
- Minimum strategy: bet $1\$$ each time.

If $p < 0.5$ (the odds are against you) which is the better strategy? What about $p = 0.5$ or
$p > 0.5$?

Comment: Please note that this is no full answer. If $p \lt 0.5$, the maximum strategy is best: you need to be "lucky" 4 times to hit the \$1000, which is a lot more likely than getting a positive strike in hundreds of attempts. If $p \gt 0.5$, the minimum strategy is best: if you're "unlucky" you lose the \$100 in one of the 4 attempts, but in the long haul, betting \$1 over and over is more likely to gain cash. For $p = 0.5$, both strategies are equally good.

Comment: @jvdhooft Looks like a good answer to me

Comment: @jvdhooft These strategies are very similar to what I came up with. However, I don't think for $p=0.5$ betting everything every time is as good as betting $1$ each time. Here, betting $1$ each time yields winning with probability $10/100 = 1/10$ (it's a simple random walk with equal weights) whereas you'd need to win four maximum bets, probability of $1/16$ to win with maximum strategy. A better maximum strategy is betting everything up until you are close enough to 1000, then bet just enough to reach 1000. For example, if you're at 700, betting 300 is strictly better than betting 700.

Comment: @Roy The OP mentioned exactly what you are saying: bet everything if you have less than $500, or bet the difference with \$1000 if you don't. While it is true that the probability is 1/16 to have \$1000 after four bets, there still is a probability of 3/5 to win when you lose the fourth bet, since you will have \$600 left after losing your \$200 bet. [This code](https://www.online-python.com/M5brYC9RHp) simulates both scenarios, yet with a \$10 bet to increase the running time of the minimal strategy. You will observe a winning frequency of approximately 10% for both strategies.

Comment: @jvdhooft You're right. Sorry I wasn't careful in reading the OP's strategy.  I actually wrote out the system of equations for the maximum strategy when $p=1/2,$ and the system is somewhat ymmetric about the middle term(s), and it wasn't too hard to show that it indeed yields probabilities proportional to how much you start with $n/m$ where you start with $n$ and want to get to $m,$ which is the same as the minimum strategy. So the two strategies do perform the same for $p=1/2$ which is a bit surprising to me.

Comment: For $p = 0.5$ every strategy where you end up with 0 or exactly 1000 (ie. if you're over 500 you don't overbet) yields the same probability, since the graph is just linear.